# Introductory phrase describing the fact that the speaker and some others were surprised

Tags: phrase-request

> **To my biggest surprise and that of the others**, he suddenly started
>   speaking fluently in Japanese.

or

> **To my and others' biggest surprise**, he suddenly started
>   speaking fluently in Japanese.

or

> **To the biggest surprise of mine and of others'**, he suddenly started
>   speaking fluently in Japanese.

or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those are quite wordy, and a little muddled.

If the speaker can be grouped with the others, I'd phrase it:

**To our enormous surprise**, he suddenly started speaking fluent Japanese.

If it's important that the speaker is separated from the group, I'd say:

**To my--and many others'--enormous surprise**, he suddenly started speaking fluent Japanese.

Unless this is a list of things that were surprising, I would replace **biggest** (a comparative adjective) with a word like **enormous** or **immense** that would maintain the sense of largeness without implying a comparison.